# GitlabCI : trigger pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have 2 pipelines on gitlab CI, and i want to add a dependency on them. That is, when the first pipeline completes without errors, execute the other.

- Pipeline 1 : unit test, lint + build
- Pipeline 2: run automated tests

About pipeline 2:

- needs to be executed once or twice a day
- needs to be triggered after successful build of Pipeline 1

Any clues on how to achieve this on the gitlab-ci file?

Comment: What's your version of gitlab ? and what's your support plan (if you have one) ?

Comment: community edition - 12.3.5

Answer (score 1):

### For scheduling

You can [schedule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html) your pipeline by configuring the interval in the UI.

In your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you can trigger job only if the schedule is triggered using the keyword `only:` or on the contrary bypass job if the scheduled is triggered using `except:` keyword

### For pipeline link

If you gitlab version is at least 11.8 and you have a **premium** account, you can specify a [downstream](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#specifying-a-downstream-pipeline-branch) pipeline using the `trigger:` keyword by specifiying a project name and a branch name.

Otherwise, you can link jobs (not pipeline) using `needs:` [keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs). Depending job will run as soon as the parent job finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
stages:
    - lint
    - test

lint:
    stage: lint
    script:
        - echo "lint"

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "test"
```